# Expire Cookie From LoginView

Tags: c#, loginview

I want to expire my login cookie whenever the LoginView in my asp.net application is clicked.  I've tried running the code OnViewChanged and OnViewChanging, but the code doesn't seem to execute.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
                OnViewChanging="HeadLoginView_ViewChanging">

    protected void HeadLoginView_ViewChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["storeNum"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("storeNum");
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
        }
    }
```

My login.aspx page checks for this cookie on Page_Load and automatically redirects the user to the main page of the site saving them the trouble of logging in.  But if they choose to log back in, I want to expire the cookie allowing the login page to load.  If I click the loginview, I just keep getting redirected back to the main page because the code to expire the cookie never seems to run.  I know this is probably simple as hell, but I am new to C# and am self taught.  Please do not send comments just to remark on how easy this should be as I am well aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the ViewChange events will work for this.

A simple solution to this would be to add a "forceLogout" parameter to the login url displayed in the "LoggedInTemplate".   Look for the parameter in the Page_Load method of your login page.   If it's not there, go ahead and do the redirect.   If it is there, then log the user out and don't do the redirect.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["forceLogout"]))
    {
        // log the user out 
    }
    else
    {
        // Your original logic
    }
}
```